# I would like to control Form1 from Form2

Tags: c#, winforms

So I want basically the user to login in first in order to use the other form. However, my dilemma is that the login box is in Form2, and the main form is Form1.

```
if ((struseremail.Equals(username)) && (strpasswd.Equals(password)))
{
  MessageBox.Show("Logged in");
  form1.Visible = true;
  form1.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
}
else
{
  MessageBox.Show("Wow, how did you screw this one up?");
}
```

However, Form1 doesn't become visible, (since I launch it as visble = false) after they log in. Can someone help?

EDIT:

Brilliant response, but my problem is still here. I basically want to load Form2 First, (which is easy I run Form1 and set it to hide) But when Form2 is closed, I want Form1 to be closed as well.

```
private void Form2_FormClosing(Object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
  Form1 form1 = new Form1();
  form1.Close();
  MessageBox.Show("Closing");
}
```

this doesn't seem to work...

Comment: edited my answer to close form1 when form2 is closed. call `form1.Close()` on `Form2_closed` event.

Answer (score 10):

You will need to pass the reference of one form to another, so that it can be used in the other form. Here I've given an example of how two different forms can communicate with each other. This example modifies the text of a Label in one form from another form.

**[Download Link for Sample Project](http://demo.ruchitsurati.net/files/FormsCommunication.zip)**

//**Your Form1**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm = new Form2(this);
        frm.Show();
    }

    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return Lbl.Text; }
        set { Lbl.Text = value; }
    }
}
```

//**Your Form2**

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Form1 mainForm = null;
    public Form2(Form callingForm)
    {
        mainForm = callingForm as Form1; 
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.mainForm.LabelText = txtMessage.Text;
    }

    //Added later, closing Form1 when Form2 is closed.
    private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        mainForm.Close();
    }
}
```

[image]
<sub>(source: [ruchitsurati.net](http://demo.ruchitsurati.net/files/frm1.png))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [ruchitsurati.net](http://demo.ruchitsurati.net/files/frm2.png))</sub>

Comment: Hook the form2.Closed event from form1 and close form1 when it's invoked.

Answer (score 0):

When you log in and do `Form1.visible = true;` have you also tried `Form1.Show();` that should show form2

However, Personally, I would prefer setting the application to run `form2` directly in the `program.cs` file.

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.Run(new Form2());
}
```

then when user successfully logs in, do

```
form1.Show();
this.Hide(); // this part is up to you
```

mind you, in form2, when / after you instantiate form1, you might want to also add this :

```
newform1.FormClosed += delegate(System.Object o, FormClosedEventArgs earg)
               { this.Close(); };
```

this closes form2 when form1 is closed

better yet do `form1.Show()` in a new thread, and then `this.Close();` for form2. this removes the need of adding to the form2's `FormClosed` event: you can thus close form2 immediately after starting form1 in a new thread. But working with threads might get a little complicated.

EDIT: 
form2 is form1's parent. if form2 is your main application form, closing it closes your program (generally). Thus you either want to just hide and disable form2, and close it only after form1 is closed, or start form1 in a new thread. Your edit pretty much opens form1, then immediately closes it.