# Transferring data from Form2 (textbox2) to Form1 (textbox1)?

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I would like to control Form1 from Form2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146576/i-would-like-to-control-form1-from-form2)

I'm a newbie to `C#` and I can't find the answer I'm looking for in google, so I'm hoping someone here could help me. I'm only practicing to transfer data *(or pass, call it however you want)* from a form to another.

Here's what I have:

I have 2 forms - `Form1` and `Form2`.
`Form1` contains a textbox (named `txtForm1`) and a button (named `btnForm1`).
`Form2` contains a textbox (named `txtForm2`) and a button (named `btnForm2`).

After running the application, by clicking the button `btnForm1`, the user opens `Form2`. The text that the user writes in the textbox (`txtForm2`) should be transfered to the textbox (`txtForm1`, which button is disabled) in `Form1`.

How can I do this transfer?

Edited:
Okay i need to be clear that this is all the code i have:

**Form1** (button which opens **Form2**):

```
    private void btnForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form2().Show();
    }
```

**Form2** (button which closes **Form2**):

```
    private void btnForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

I have NOTHING ELSE. (I'm a total newbie)

Comment: Is it a WinForms or WPF application?

Answer (score 0):

Make a public variable and pass it the value from your text box and then onto your second form.

```
public static string myVar;   
myVar = txtForm2.Text;
```

and when you return to the first form:
`txtForm1.Text = Form2.myVar;`

Comment: @Rotem I just do it for ease of access. Should I not?

Comment: making it `public` shout make it accessible from everywhere as long as you have the reference to the instance. Making it `static` means the value will be shared among all `Form2` instances.

Comment: making static allows me to access it through `form2.` notation, or am I wrong? I find it easier to remember.

Comment: It allows you to access it through the class name (probably `Form2`) and not the instance. You should be aware of the other implications of it though. It might be fine in your specific case, but it's not very good practice unless `Form2` is a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

In your Form2 you should have some like:

```
private void btnForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {          
   this.Hide();       
 }


public String GettxtForm2()
{
    return txtForm2.Text;
}
```

Now in form1 you can acces that txtForm2 with something like:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2();
 //on click btnForm1 show that form2 where you can edit the txtForm2
 private void btnForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {                
       form2.Show();       
     }
   //after you save the txtForm2 when you will focus back to form1 the txtForm1 will get the value from txtForm2
   private void Form1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             txtForm1.Text = Form2.GettxtForm2();
        }
```

You can easy modify the events where all this logic can occur...

Answer (score 0):

in `Form1`:

```
public void SetTextboxText(String text)
{
    txtForm1.Text = text;
}

private void btnForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var frm = new Form2(this); // pass parent form (this) in constructor
    frm.Show();
}
```

in `Form2`:

```
Form _parentForm;

public Form2(Form form)
{
    _parentForm = form;
}

private void txtForm2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _parentForm.SetTextboxText(txtForm2.Text); // change Form1.txtForm1.Text
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this ;)

On Form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 frm2 = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
        frm2.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

On form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public string textBoxValue;
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Form2(string textBoxValue)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.textBoxValue = textBoxValue;
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBoxValue;
    }
```