# Transfering data from Form2 (textbox2) to Form1 (textbox1)?

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Transfering data from Form2 (textbox2) to Form1 (textbox1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14212032/transfering-data-from-form2-textbox2-to-form1-textbox1)

I'm a newbie to `C#` and I can't find the answer I'm looking for in google, so I'm hoping someone here could help me. I'm only practicing to transfer data *(or pass, call it however you want)* from a form to another.

Here's what i have :

I have 2 forms - `Form1` and `Form2`.
`Form1` contains a textbox (named `txtForm1`) and a button (named `btnForm1`).
`Form2` contains a textbox (named `txtForm2`) and a button (named `btnForm2`).

After running the application, by clicking the button `btnForm1`, the user opens `Form2`. The text that the user writes in the textbox (`txtForm2`) should be transfered to the textbox (`txtForm1`), which button is disabled) in `Form1`.

How can I do this transfer ? Please help.

Okay i need to be clear that this is all the code i have:

`Form1` (button which opens `Form2`):

```
    private void btnForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form2().Show();
    }
```

`Form2` (button which closes `Form2`):

```
    private void btnForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```

I have NOTHING ELSE. (I'm a total newbie)

Comment: You have already received 3 or 4 answers on your first thread.

Answer (score 1):

On Form1:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2(textBox1.Text);
    frm2.Show();
    this.Hide();
}
```

On form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
public string textBoxValue;
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public Form2(string textBoxValue)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.textBoxValue = textBoxValue;
}

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = textBoxValue;
}
```

Comment: why do you need public string textBoxValue ?

Comment: I guess you don't have to make it public

Comment: I would say you don't need this variable at all

Comment: @VladL If I remove the variable the code doesn't work. Maybe you can give some sample code? Then I can learn a better way of doing it?

Comment: see my answer. this is correct OOP implementation

Answer (score 1):

On Form1:

```
private void btnForm1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form2 frm2 = new Form2(txtForm1.Text);
    frm2.ShowDialog();
    txtForm1.Text = frm2.GetText;
}
```

On form2:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
  public string GetText { get {return txtForm2.Text;} }
  public Form2()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
  }

  public Form2(string textBoxValue)
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.txtForm2.Text = textBoxValue;
  }

private void btnForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
}
```