# Winform handling

Tags: c#, .net, forms, visibility

I have 3 forms.
We can enter to form2 through form1.(Then form1 will disappear.)
When we close form2, form1 will reappear.
Similarly we can enter to form3 through form2.(Then form2 will disappear.)
When we close form3, form2 should reappear.(This is the part where I fail.)

When I close the form3, the form which appear is the form1 instead of form2.
(same instances have to reappear. 'Creating new object of form and make it appear' is not allowed :) )

Please help.

code in form1:

```
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        this.Visible = false;
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog();
        this.Visible = true;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
```

code in form2:

```
        this.Visible = false;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        Form3 f3 = new Form3();
        f3.ShowDialog();
        this.Visible = true;
        this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
```

Comment: Where's the code for `Form3`?

Comment: There's no form_closed event code ..

Comment: I haven't any closed event code for form3.
The above two code groups are implemented as button click events.
When I close the form by titlebar icon, form2,form1 actions are working fine.

Comment: "This is where I fail" falls in the "It doesn't work" category.  Nobody knows what that means.  Taking a pot-shot at it, minimize whatever window comes to the foreground to find your form back.  That's what happens when you close a dialog and there isn't any window left that can receive the focus.  A window of another app gets the focus.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3146576/i-would-like-to-control-form1-from-form2

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but try make form2's parent be form1:

```
form2.Parent=form1;
```

or

```
f2.ShowDialog(form1);
```

Comment: Will you please explain? @David

Comment: @jubairusman, I think it is clear that if you don't specify the parent, form2 will be parent of the desktop. Since you explicitly specified the parent, when form1 will bring its child form, which is form2, to front.